# How to scrape multiple quotes pages data using scrapy

Tags: python, automation, scrapy

I have develop a code to scrape single page's data but I don't know that how to scrape multiple data by using my scrapy code

```py
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quote'
    start_urls = ['https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/love?page=2']

    def parse(self, response):
        url=response.url
        text=response.css(".mediumText:nth-child(2) .quoteText::text").get().strip()
        author=response.css(".mediumText:nth-child(2) .authorOrTitle::text").get().strip()
        yield{"text":text,"author":author,"url":url }
```

screenshots: https://prnt.sc/pd3ei5z-9VwZ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To scrape multiple items on the page you need to iterate through a selector for each quote item such as in the example below and then yield of each of them.

I have also added in code to go to the next pages and scrape those as well.

```py
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quote'
    start_urls = ['https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/love']

    def parse(self, response):

        for quote in response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'quoteDetails')]"):
            yield {
                'url': response.url,
                'text': quote.xpath("normalize-space(./div[@class='quoteText']/text())").get(),
                'author': quote.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='authorOrTitle']/text())").get()
            }

        # go to next page
        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='next_page']/@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page)
```